# sum,count,distinct count fields with awk

Tags: shell, awk

I have a text file like this:

```
A   B   C   D   E
----------------------  
x   x   e   2   10
y   y   g   1   8 
z   o   e   2   9 
o   o   q   1   10
p   z   e   3   22
x   x   e   1   11
z   o   a   1   24
y   z   b   1   25
```

I want to use `awk` do the same thing as this `SQL` does:

```
select A, 
       B, 
       count(distinct C), 
       sum(D),
       sum(case when E>20 then E else 0 END) 
  from test 
 group by A,B
```

output:

```
A   B  count(distinct C)    sum(D)  sum(case when E>20 then E else 0 END) 
-------------------------------------------------------
o   o   1       1       0
p   z   1       3       22
x   x   1       3       0
y   y   1       1       0
y   z   1       1       25
z   o   2       3       24
```

Here is my solution but the distinct part is not completed:

```
awk '
{
    idx4[$1"|"$2]=idx4[$1"|"$2]+$4;
    idx5[$1"|"$2]=$5>20?idx5[$1"|"$2]+$5:idx5[$1"|"$2]
} 
END {
    for (i in idx4) print i, idx4[i], idx5[i]
}' OFS="\t" test
```

=============================================================================

I have completed this by hours, here is my code:

```
    {
        if (idx3[$1"|"$2, $3] == 0) {
            idx3[$1"|"$2, $3]+=1;
        }
        idx4[$1"|"$2]=idx4[$1"|"$2]+$4;
        idx5[$1"|"$2]=$5>20?idx5[$1"|"$2]+$5:idx5[$1"|"$2]
    } 
    END {
        for (j in idx3) {
            split(j, idx, SUBSEP)
            count[idx[1]]++
        }
        for (i in idx4) {
            print i, count[i], idx4[i], idx5[i] 
        }
    } OFS="\t"
```

@Scrutinizer has given a more readable code below, i think that is better.

Comment: I would be easier if you just posted the expected output.

Comment: i have edited the question, the output is given, thanks @sudo_O

Comment: by string match you can count the distict column; another way,1) sort the rows by column A&b, 2)then awk scan compare A,B if chenged then start new counting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (similar to your own solution):

```
awk '
  NR<3{
    next
  }

  {
    i=$1 OFS $2
    D[i]+=$4
  }

  !A[i,$3]++{
    C[i]++
  }

  $5>20{
    E[i]+=$5
  }

  END{
    for(i in D)print i, C[i], D[i], E[i]+0
  }
' OFS='\t' infile
```

`NR<3` is used to skip the two header lines. If they are not present in the input file you can leave that section out.

Answer (score 1):

please try this script, I had test it can oupt the result as you expect.

```
awk '
{
    if( NR<3) {next}

    idx4[$1"|"$2]=idx4[$1"|"$2]+$4;
    idx5[$1"|"$2]=$5>20?idx5[$1"|"$2]+$5:idx5[$1"|"$2]

    if( index(TR[$1"|"$2],$3)==0 )
    {
         TR[$1"|"$2] = TR[$1"|"$2]"|"$3;
         TRD[$1"|"$2] +=1;
    }
} 
END {
    for (i in idx4) print i, TRD[i], idx4[i], idx5[i]+0
}' OFS="\t" test
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ gawk '{ a[$1,$2]["C"][$3]; a[$1,$2]["D"]+=$4; a[$1,$2]["E"]+=($5>20 ? $5:0) }
END { 
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
    for ( i in a) { 
        split(i, b, SUBSEP) 
        print b[1], b[2], length(a[i]["C"]), a[i]["D"], a[i]["E"] 
    }
}' OFS='\t' file
o       o       1       1       0
p       z       1       3       22
x       x       1       3       0
y       y       1       1       0
y       z       1       1       25
z       o       2       3       24
```